# How to define a metric from a measure and a similarity ordering?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

Suppose that I have a space in which there is what I'll call a similarity ordering on points.  That is, I have a similarity function $s(\cdot,\cdot)$, such that for any two pairs of points $\{x_1,x_2\}$ and $\{y_1,y_2\}$, either $s(x_1,x_2)\leq s(y_1,y_2)$ or $s(y_1,y_2)\leq s(x_1,x_2)$.

$s$ is not a metric.  It does not return numbers.  It just generates the ordering.  (Is there an official term for this kind of ordering on pairs?)

Suppose in addition, there's a measure on the space.

Is there a way to define a metric on the points (not the pairs) from these two assumptions alone?  Are there well-known examples of such metrics?  Is there something else that one would need to assume?

Comment: Right now one could define any metric in the world (the discrete metric, for example). Do you want the metric to be related to the ordering and/or the measure in some particular way? Also, if the function $s$ doesn't return numbers, then it seems one could simply define an ordering on the ordered pairs themselves rather than their images under this function. (There's a typo in the second inequality, I gather.)

Comment: Thanks @GregMartin. Yes, I want both the measure and the order to be used. The context is that I am criticizing some applications of mathematical ideas because they depend on already having a metric (and on a measure, but you can use Lebesgue measure in the context.) I don't think there are always good reasons to think that there is a metric that bears the right relationship to the application. I'm wondering if there's a response that says "But you assume similarity and a measure, and that gives us a metric that makes sense here." (Fixed the typo. Thanks. Sorry for delay in replying--busy.)

Comment: I don't want to assume that the points are in a Euclidean space or are numeric, vectors, etc. That's why I need the ()
function. It says points are more similar to each other than which other points. (The points probably are specifiable by vectors, but the numeric values aren't particularly meaningful.)  I don't expect anyone else to assess what "makes sense here", but I am wondering if there are well-known ways to build a metric from a measure and an order.